# Wordpress add_rewrite_rules for custom URLs ending in .html

Tags: php, htaccess, url-rewriting, plugins

It's pretty common to see Wordpress running on pretty permalinks in the style of:

```
/blog/2012/04/my-post/
```

However I'm trying to customize a fresh Wordpress install with a different set of URLs. I believe wp_rewrite is my best method, writing a small block of code inside functions.php. I have seen a few examples of wp_rewrite_rules but none appear to be simply changing all post URLs.

Ideally I'd like to have them setup like this:

```
/blog/2012/04/my-post.html
```

I would love any help on this if possible.. it's been a struggle finding good code examples for even basic rewrite rules. Let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using wp_rewrite to make URLs ending in .html](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48651/using-wp-rewrite-to-make-urls-ending-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need custom rewrites for that, you can simply use the permalinks settings to achieve those results. Click the Custom Structure option and enter:

```
/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

Comment: This is a great answer.